# A-priori probability in pattern recognition problem

Tags: probability, pattern-recognition

I am trying to evaluate a formula for a pattern recognition problem but am having difficulty understanding what an a-priori probability is.

Suppose I have a dataset with 4 classes. 25% of the examples are in class 1, 25% are in class 2, 40 % are in class 3, and 10 % in class 4.

I now need to calculate the a-priori probability for each class. Most of the definitions I have found basically say something like ["A priori probability is calculated by logically examining a circumstance or existing information regarding a situation."](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/apriori.asp) and I have seen many examples using a coin toss where the apriori probability for heads and tails is .5 for each case.

With the coin toss example in mind, I am tempted to say the a-priori probability of each class is .25 since I have 4 classes.

Or do I take into account the dataset when determining this probability (e.g a priori probability for class 3 is .4)? To me that seems more like an empirical probability since it is based on data. I would greatly appreciate some clarification.

Comment: If you knew nothing at all about the distribution before you sampled, using $.25$ for each of them at least has the advantage of being unbiased.

Comment: It seems to me that it depends on how the samples were acquired.  If they were acquired through some kind of random sampling, then perhaps the empirical probabilities make the most sense as *a priori* probabilities.  If they are just from public sources, then maybe $.25$ each is the best you can do.  We need to have the "circumstance or existing information" on which to base a judgment, and even then, reasonable people can differ.

Comment: @saulspatz the dataset is Fisher’s iris dataset https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set